# Angular Service: providedIn issue with circular dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, service, module

First of all, I'm new to Angular's world, with some experience from AngualarJS (useless here hahaha)

I'm following [this link](https://www.maestralsolutions.com/angular-application-state-management-you-do-not-need-external-data-stores/) in order to have a Service/State for a specific Module.

But as soon as I use it inside the very module, I get a circular dependency `Warning: Circular dependency detected`

How could I possibly use such a `providedIn` property to set a Module, if I get this error?

`home-store.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeModule } from './home.module';

export interface IHomeState {
  user?: any;
}

@Injectable({ providedIn: HomeModule }) // I'd like to restrict this service to HomeModule
export class HomeStoreService {}
```

`home-module.ts`

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild([])],
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

`home-component.ts`

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeStoreService } from './home-store.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(private homeStore: HomeStoreService) {}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not to use the providedIn, becuase you dont need it.
So, you can change your code like that and have the same results.

home-store.service.ts

```
export interface IHomeState {
  user?: any;
}

export class HomeStoreService {}
```

home-module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import { HomeStoreService } from 'path/to/service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild([])],
  providers: [HomeStoreService]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

home-component.ts Without changes

Comment: that works wonderfully. I assume with `providers` array I still get lazy-loading right? but, I can check that myself. Thank you!

Comment: Yes lazy-loading, but no tree shaking

Comment: The HomeStoreService does not get destroyed once I navigate to another route/module. Is that because we used `providers` array instead of `providedIn` on the decorator?

Comment: The answers is no. add ProvidedIn or just add providers on module have the same results.

You can try, add implements OnDestroy on a service and put a console log inside.
When i try, it works perfectly and when I navigate to another module, the services get destroyed

Comment: I still need to decorate the service with empty `@Injectable()`, right? otherwise I get: `Class is using Angular features but is not decorated. Please add an explicit Angular decorator.`. I did so, and my `ngOnDestroy()` method is never called, I'm using Angular 11.0.0. I'm also lazy-loading my modules with `loadChildren`

Comment: perhaps I need to start another Stackoverflow question hehe